unable to install of pgadmin4 i did not know why i am getting this error
GPG error: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8881B2A8210976F2
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

how do i fix this error

You didn't provide the public key for the repository: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available. You need to get the key from the repo's website, put it into a file on your system and refer the repo to that file. The details depend on the Ubuntu version you use and how exactly the repo offers its key.
